# In metric space, countable union of compact sets is separable

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

I'm trying to prove the next statement:

> If $(X,d)$ is a metric space and $K_n\subseteq X$ a compact sub-set for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ then: $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}K_n$ is separable.

In my attempt I tried to use the fact that a compact metric space is separable:

Let $X_n\subseteq K_n$ be the dense sub-set of $K_n$  for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

I guess that the union of $X_n$ was the dense subset of $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}K_n$, so first notice that:

$cl(X_n)=K_n\implies
\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}cl(X_n)=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}K_n$

and $X_n\subseteq\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}X_n\implies cl(X_n)\subseteq cl(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}X_n)\implies \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}cl(X_n)\subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}cl(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}X_n)=cl(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}X_n)
$

so $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}K_n\subseteq cl(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}X_n)$

But in the $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}K_n\supseteq cl(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}X_n)$ part, I'm stuck.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You don't have to prove this, and generally it may not even be true.  For example if you take an increasing sequence of closed discs whose union is an open disc, and you take  dense subsets for instance the rational points at each stage - then the rational points in an open disc will have as closure the closed disc containing the open disc.

Comment: In general, a countable union of separable spaces is separable. With your above notation, just show that $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}X_n$ meets each non-empty open set. (However, if you argue with the $cl$ operator, you should carefully check, in which space you consider the closures.) Hence, using that a compact metric space is separable, as you mentioned, you are done.

Comment: @user941248: the statement is true, see my above comment. In your example, the open disc is separable, indeed, although not closed, hence not compact.

Comment: @user941248 that example with the disks is not a counterexample to the thing the OP thinks to be true..

Comment: You only have to show that every point of $\bigcup_n K_n$ is in the closure of $\bigcup_n X_n$...

Comment: You can also note $\bigcup_n K_n$ is obviously Lindelöf (and hence separable in a metric space).

Comment: With the $\cup_{n}K_{n}\subseteq cl(\cup_{n}X_{n})$ I have that every point in $\cup_{n}K_{n}$ is in the clousure of $\cup_{n}X_{n}$ but I know that I need the equality for $\cup_{n}X_{n}$ to be dense in $\cup_{n}K_{n}$

Answer (score 1):

If $x \in \bigcup_n K_n$, then $x \in K_m$ for some $m$, so $x \in \operatorname{cl}(X_m) \subseteq \operatorname{cl}(\bigcup_n X_n)$. It follows that $\bigcup_n X_n$ indeed is dense in $\bigcup_n K_n$.

Comment: My problem here is that with what you wrote I can assure the $\cup_{n}K_{n}\subseteq cl(\cup_{n}X_{n})$, but I don't see why is that enough to get the equality.

Comment: @JoséDanielCastilladelValle equality is not needed.$Y$ separable means there is a countable subset $D$ such that every point of $Y$ is in the closure of $D$.